# Why does json encoding an empty array in code return null?

Tags: json, go

So I have a types like this

```
type TextTagRelationship struct {
  Id int64 `json:"id"`
  TagId int64 `json:"tag_id"`
  TaggedText string `json:"tagged_text"`
  TagName string `json:"tag_name"`
  PageNumber int64 `json:"page_number"`
  Color string `json:"color"`
}

type TextTagRelationships []TextTagRelationship
```

Now, I have a handler that does something like this

```
func getTaggedTextForPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    pageNumber, err := strconv.ParseInt(vars["pageNumber"], 10, 64)
    check(err)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * from tagged_text WHERE page_number = ?", pageNumber)
    check(err)
    var textTagRelationships []TextTagRelationship
    var textTagRelationship TextTagRelationship
    for rows.Next() {
        //execute sql code here
        textTagRelationships = append(textTagRelationships, textTagRelationship)
    }


    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(textTagRelationships); err != nil {
        check(err)
    }
}
```

This works fine if there are actual rows, but when encoding an empty array `textTagRelationships`, in my response in the chrome console I get a `null`. Why is this happening? It looks like `textTagRelationships` is actually a `[]` and so I would have expected the encoding to encode a `[]` and my response to have a `[]`.

Comment: Sounds like `textTagRelationships` is `nil`.

Comment: well, nothing happens to it. It's just inited. And when I print it out I print out an empty array.

Comment: It's declared, not inited. `var thing []type` gives you `nil` of type `[]type`. `thing := make([]type, len)` gives you an slice of type `[]type` and length `len`, and `var thing [len]type` gives you a len-length array of type `[]type` filled with the zero value for `type`.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like this is a gotcha in Go.

https://danott.co/posts/json-marshalling-empty-slices-to-empty-arrays-in-go.html

The solution around this is to not rely on the default init behaviour and actually do a `make`.

`var textTagRelationships TextTagRelationships = make(TextTagRelationships, 0)`